# How to mock mongoose query like findOne()?

Tags: mongoose, model, find, jestjs

I am going to mock mongooose function `find()`.
This is what I have tried.

1)

```
jest.mock("./user.model")
UserModel.findOne.mockResolvedValue(await UserModel.findOne({email: "test@gmail.com"}))
```

2)

```
const findOne = jest.fn();
findOne.mockResolvedValue(await UserModel.findOne({email: "test@gmail.com"}))
```

But both not working,
What is solution? I would like to make findOne of UserModel to return specific record always.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

assuming that `UserModel` is a [mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne) model instance, you can probably do something along the lines of:

```
jest.spyOn(UserModel, 'findOne').mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve({ email: "test@gmail.com" }))
```

Some jest references:

- [mockReturnValue](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnvaluevalue)
- [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname)

Comment: Thanks very much, btw, can I use same way for user.save() ?
I tried but it fails, please help me with it.

Comment: I think you could use the create method. Like this UserModel.create() instead of userInstance.save()